# how to create aws cdk stack containing 2 memoryDB instances

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, infrastructure-as-code, amazon-memory-db

I am new to AWS and I have to create a IAAC cdk containing 2 memory DB instances in a stack.
I tried using the following example but it is written in python and I dont know that very well.
https://github.com/ksmin23/my-aws-cdk-examples/blob/main/memorydb/app.py

Can anyone help me with creating this cdk using java or share any examples in java.
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would need to share you attempts and where you're getting stuck. Have you set up an example CDK application?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.